# Modernizr Feature Detection with v3

Tags: html, css, modernizr

I would like to ask if there's any significant difference/performance issue for detecting using the following two methods:

Let's say we're testing for 3d transforms.

Using the new function that Modernizr 3 offers:

```
Modernizr.on('csstransforms3d', function(result) {
  if (result) {
    element.className = 'myFirstClass';
  }
  else {
    element.className = 'mySecondClass';
  }
});
```

And with the standard way:

```
if (Modernizr.csstransforms3d) {
  element.className = 'myFirstClass';
} else {
  element.className = 'mySecondClass'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Modernizr.on` function is only (or mainly) for *asynchronous detects* and *deferred actions*. See the [full explanation and example](https://github.com/stucox/modernizr-on/) by @stucox for more details.

`csstransforms3d` is not async, and available right away. There would be  no reason to be using the `on` *event callback* method for it. The function is rather inefficient with `setTimeout()` calls which aren't good for performance.

Only use `on` for deferred `events` on async detects.

Answer (score 1):

They aren't really comparable because depending on the situation, one will always be better suited than the other. Performance isn't really the issue.

The standard way, checking `Boolean` values in a `Dictionary` is an extremely fast operation. If you have a function that gets executed in reaction to some user interaction, this will be the best way to get feature info. For example:

```
$('#showVideo').on('click', function() {
    if (Modernizr.video) {
        // load HTML5 video
    }
    else {
        // load Flash video
    }
});
```

Similarly, listening to JS events is very efficient. What the new event-based model in Modernizr allows is for you to react to the Modernizr tests completing. This is great if your site needs to make changes ASAP when feature detection data is available. For example:

```
Modernizr.on('draganddrop', function(result) {
    if (!result) {
        alert('This site requires Drag and Drop. Please update your browser.')
    }
});
```

Previously you had to watch for DOM updates on the `<body>` and check the classes in order to get this information.